# Поиск по имени и фамилии

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет. Довольно глупая проблема, но трудность появилась. Нужно сделать правильный запрос по поиску пользователей по имени и фамилии:

1. Если введено имя, то всех с таким именем показывать.
2. Если введена фамилия, то всех с такой фамилией показывать.
3. Если введено имя и фамилия, то искать совпадения не зависимо от порядка.

Два поля: `first_name, last_name` - имя и фамилия.

Получается сделать только поиск именно по имени или фамилии, а по тому и тому не получается.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE first_name LIKE '%$s%' or last_name LIKE '%$s%' LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Есть 2 таблицы: одна с именами, вторая с фамилиями? Или это поля?

Comment: Да, поля. Опечатка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В запросе можно ещё использовать синтаксис AND:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE first_name LIKE '%$s%' AND last_name LIKE '%$s%' LIMIT 10
```

а уже введены ли фамилия/имя/фамилия и имя - ты уже должен проверять через пременные полученные из формы, обработать не забудь!

Это для 2ух полей одной таблицы, а если у тебя это в разных таблицах что не хорошо, то через INNER JOIN.

Comment: OK. AND здесь в запросе в принципе не нужен, обойтись можно OR'ом.
Совет подвиг меня на мысль решению проблемы. Спасибо.

Comment: Дерзай! :)